# RAD Studio: Cannot resolve unit name 'pFIBDatabase' (Installed package)

Tags: delphi, pascal, rad-studio

Is there something missing so that I cannot include the package in a simple console application that was cloned from this GitHub repository: [FIB](https://github.com/madorin/fibplus)?

1. I've tried compiling the fibplus/FIBPlus_D26.drpoj and also FIBPlusEditors_D26.dproj, I've built the 2 projects, and installed them.
2. I've tried including the library paths in Tools -> Options -> Language -> Delphi -> Library path
3. The two components do appear in Component -> Install Packages... (Design Packages) [image: Library paths]

Why could the components be missing still? Is there an installation process or a procedure missing?

(IDE: Rad Studio 10.3 Rio).

[image]

Comment: Look at the examples. Most have `FIBDataSet, pFIBDataSet, FIBDatabase, pFIBDatabase` in the `uses`.

Comment: @Brian, yes, there are example but I might be missing a package installation concept in Delphi, is there a common way to fix missing packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was to go "Tools -> Options -> Language -> Delphi -> Library path" and manually include the library paths that were mising, e.g. "..Downloads\Repositories\fibplus" - the main folder containing file "FIBPlus.inc" were missing, and the IDE showed the error that the file was missing.

Just manually search for the files that Rad Studio was missing, insert them into library path and that's it.